# I have schema CSV file with variable types, workbench can't understand it, how to import this CSV format?

Tags: sql, csv, backendless

```
"bio({""constraints"":[],""type"":""STRING"",""dataSize"":500})","birthday({""constraints"":[],""type"":""DATETIME""})","chattiness({""constraints"":[],""type"":""INT"",""defaultValue"":""1""})","firstName({""constraints"":[],""type"":""STRING"",""dataSize"":250})","gender({""constraints"":[],""type"":""BOOLEAN"",""dataSize"":500})","image({""constraints"":[],""type"":""FILE_REF"",""dataSize"":500,""defaultValue"":""""})","lastName({""constraints"":[],""type"":""STRING"",""dataSize"":500})","token({""constraints"":[],""type"":""STRING"",""dataSize"":500,""dynamicProps"":{""localData"":{}}})","objectId({""constraints"":[],""type"":""STRING_ID"",""dataSize"":36})","ownerId({""constraints"":[],""type"":""STRING"",""dataSize"":36})","created({""constraints"":[],""type"":""DATETIME""})","updated({""constraints"":[],""type"":""DATETIME""})","countryInformations({""constraints"":[],""type"":""RELATION"",""autoLoad"":false,""relatedTable"":""countryInformation""})","statistics({""constraints"":[""UQ""],""type"":""RELATION"",""autoLoad"":false,""relatedTable"":""userStatistics""})"
```

I got this CSV as I exported Person table from Backendless.com. I never saw such CSV format. does this structure has a proper name that I can look up on the internet? is there any software that can read it and accordingly import it to a mysql db?

Comment: Well, that's obviously not a CSV.  I'm not sure why people are calling every structured data text file a CSV.  It's also not JSON, although it's close.  Those function-like calls are a handy separator, but it will make it harder to parse.  Is that all there is?  Because it would be pretty easy to translate that by hand.

Comment: I totally agree. For me, it's frustrating that they don't provide a "simple" dump file functionality. It was a bad idea to lock our backend in a managed service.

Comment: No, that's not all, this is just an example, there're more tables and data...

Comment: CSV stands for "Comma Separated Value". There is no "standard" for CSV other other than separating values by comma and escaping values containing commas and sometimes quotes. So saying that "it is not a CSV" is a complete nonsense. There are no "function like calls" here, simply a metadata in the header row describing what the data type is and what constraints it has.

Comment: @MarkPiller the problem is that the file is only compatible with Backendless, and I need to enter the types manually if I want to copy the schema to a DB.

Comment: @HassanKanso there is no single universal standard for defining types in CSV. Remove the header row and you have  CSV without our metadata

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to withdraw my objection to calling this a CSV file.  That's exactly what it is.  This doesn't do the whole job, but maybe this will give you a start.  This assumes there is only one line in the file; if you have multiple tables in separate files, then you'd need a loop instead of using `next()` on the `cvs.reader`.

```
import json
import csv

row = next(csv.reader(open('x.txt')))
for f in row:
    column,_,rest = f.partition('(')
    data = json.loads(rest[:-1])
    print(column, data)
```

Now you can print `data['type']` and `data['dataSize']`.  There are still some awkward things here.  It shows fields with relations to other tables, but it doesn't say what type those fields are.

Comment: done, thank you. I'm still testing the generated SQL script. Check the code in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

based on the code provided by Tim Roberts, I wrote a script that converts Backendless CSV schema to MYSQL 8.0 Schema

```
import json
import csv
from os import listdir
import mysql.connector

host="host"
user="admin"
password="admin"
database="mydb"

# when true all tables with the same names will be dropped before a new ones are created
drop_existing_tables = False
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host=host,
  user=user,
  password=password,
  database=database
)

path = "./"
filenames = listdir(path)
files = [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".csv") ]

# select table
commands = "USE " + database + ";\n"

#to be able to reference a table before it s even created.
commands += "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;\n"

def constraints_to_string(constraints):
    if len(constraints) == 0:
        return ""
    stringConstraints = ""
    addIndex = False
    for constraint in constraints:
       if constraint == "NN":
            constraint = "NOT NULL"
       if constraint == "UQ":
            constraint = "UNIQUE"
       if constraint == "IDX":
            addIndex = True
       if not addIndex:
            stringConstraints +=  " " + str(constraint)
    if addIndex:
       stringConstraints += ",\n INDEX (`" + column + "`)"
    return stringConstraints

def map_data_type(data, column, constraints):
    dataType = data["type"]
    if column == "ownerId":
        dataType = "BINARY(16) " + constraints + ", " + \
        " FOREIGN KEY (`" + column + "`) REFERENCES `users`(`objectId`)"
    elif dataType == "STRING":
        dataSize = data.get("dataSize")
        dataType = "VARCHAR(" + str(dataSize) + ") " + constraints
    elif dataType == "STRING_ID":
        dataType = "BINARY(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY " + constraints
    elif dataType == "RELATION":
        dataType = "BINARY(16) " + constraints + ", " + \
        "FOREIGN KEY (`" + column + "`) REFERENCES `" + data["relatedTable"] + "`(`objectId`)"
    elif dataType == "FILE_REF":
        dataType = "VARCHAR(256) " + constraints
    else:
        dataType += " " + constraints
    return dataType
    

# drop tables.
if drop_existing_tables:
    for file in files:
        tableName = file.rpartition('.')[0]
        commands += "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName + ";\n"
    commands += "\n"

# generate SQL scripts from backendless schema csv file.
for file in files:
    row = next(csv.reader(open(file)))
    tableName = file.rpartition('.')[0]
    variablesString = ""
    first=True
    for f in row:
        column,_,rest = f.partition('(')
        data = json.loads(rest[:-1])
        
        constraints = constraints_to_string(data.get("constraints"))
        dataType = map_data_type(data, column, constraints)
            
        if not first:
            variablesString +=  ", \n"
       
        variablesString += "`" + column + "`" + " " + dataType
        first = False        
    commands += "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" + variablesString + ");\n\n"
 
print(commands)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
results = mycursor.execute(commands, multi=True)
if input("are you sure you want to execute the SQL script above? (y/n)") != "y":
    mydb.commit()
```